# if $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ then $F(x):=\int_{-\infty }^x f(t)\,\mathrm d t$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: measure-theory

Prove that if $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ then $F(x):=\int_{-\infty }^x f(t)\,\mathrm d t$ is uniformly continue.

**Attempts**

$$|F(x)-F(y)|\leq \int_{x}^y|f(t)|\,\mathrm d t.$$
If $f$ is bounded, then the result is obvious, but how can I do in the more general case ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon >0$. By continuity of measure, there is $\delta >0$ s.t. for all measurable set $E$, $$m(E)<\delta \implies \int_E|f|<\varepsilon .$$

Therefore, if $|x-y|<\delta $, you get $$|F(x)-F(y)|<\varepsilon ,$$
as wished.

Comment: Bu the whole point is to show the first statemenr

Comment: @JonathanHole: This is a very common property... Moreover since the OP accepted the answer, I guess that he knows this result.